# Select que compare conjuntos de valores das colunas de duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

Senhores,

Primeiro, possuo 2 tabelas

Tabela 1:

```
ID    L1     L2     L3    L4     L5
------------------------------------
1     a      c      e     g      i
2     a      c      d     g      i
3     l      n      p     r      t
```

Tabela 2:

```
ID    L1    L2    L3    L4    L5    L6
----------------------------------------------
9     l     n     o     p     r     t          
8     a     c     d     e     g     i
7     a     b     c     d     e     f
```

Gostaria de um select que buscasse o conjunto de dados da Tabela 1(L1 até L5) dentro do conjunto de dados da Tabela 2 (L1 até L6), para que o resultado fosse + ou - assim:

Resultado:

```
ID    Count
-------------
9     1
8     2
7     0
```

Uma vez que o registro de ID 9 da tabela 2 possue 1 registro da Tabela 1 que caiba dentro, assim como o ID 8 tem 2 e o 7 não tem nenhum.

Agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Tem que respeita a ordem dos elementos ou não?

Comment: A ordem não importa GOKU

Comment: A resposta abaixo não resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Acredito que sim... estou testando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    T2.ID, 
    COUNT(T1.L1) AS 'Count'
FROM
    Tabela2 T2
LEFT JOIN
    Tabela1 T1 ON 
    (
        CONCAT('[', T2.L1 ,']','[', T2.L2 ,']','[', T2.L3 ,']','[', T2.L4 ,']','[', T2.L5 ,']','[', T2.L6 ,']')
        LIKE CONCAT('%[', T1.L1, ']%')

        AND 

        CONCAT('[', T2.L1 ,']','[', T2.L2 ,']','[', T2.L3 ,']','[', T2.L4 ,']','[', T2.L5 ,']','[', T2.L6 ,']')
        LIKE CONCAT('%[', T1.L2, ']%')

        AND

        CONCAT('[', T2.L1 ,']','[', T2.L2 ,']','[', T2.L3 ,']','[', T2.L4 ,']','[', T2.L5 ,']','[', T2.L6 ,']')
        LIKE CONCAT('%[', T1.L3, ']%')

        AND

        CONCAT('[', T2.L1 ,']','[', T2.L2 ,']','[', T2.L3 ,']','[', T2.L4 ,']','[', T2.L5 ,']','[', T2.L6 ,']')
        LIKE CONCAT('%[', T1.L4, ']%')

        AND

        CONCAT('[', T2.L1 ,']','[', T2.L2 ,']','[', T2.L3 ,']','[', T2.L4 ,']','[', T2.L5 ,']','[', T2.L6 ,']')
        LIKE CONCAT('%[', T1.L5, ']%')
    )
GROUP BY
    T2.ID
```

Teste realizado no MySql.
Foi selecionado todos os registros da Tabela 2 cujo a concatenação das colunas L1 a L6 contenha os valores das colunas L1 a L5 da Tabela1.

Ex.:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portando para o grupo 9 existe apenas um conjunto que cabe nele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Coloquei cada caractere entre colchetes para diferenciar caso a base de dados contenha [aaa] e [aa]. Se não tiver entre colchetes ao comparar 'aaa' like '%aa%' iria retorna verdadeiro.

Comment: Perfeito Thiagosilr, era exatamente isso que procurava.